# Convert Spring boot DTO to json to include only JsonProperty

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

```
 @JsonPropertyOrder({
     "aaaa",
     "bbb",
     "cccc"
     })

 public class myDto {
 
     @Id
     private String id;
 
     @Valid
     @NotNull
     @JsonProperty("aaaa")
     private String aaaa;
 
     @Valid
     @NotNull
     @JsonProperty("bbbb")
     private List<String> bbbb;
 
     @Valid
     @NotNull
     @JsonProperty("cccc")
     private List<String> cccc;
 
    // getter and setter for above 4
 }
```

I want to convert it to JSON to include field aaaa, bbbb, ccc only.
Expected output:  `{"aaaa":"1","bbbb":["1"],"cccc":["1"]}`

I tried to create JSON using following but it included ID field, meta, link fields as well.

```
 String test = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myDto); 
 configuration = new JSONObject(test);
```

Output: `{"aaaa":"1","bbbb":["1"],"cccc":["1"],"meta":null,"links":null,"id":null}`

Expected output:  `{"aaaa":"1","bbbb":["1"],"cccc":["1"]}`

Comment: Seems, you are looking for [`@JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use the annotation `@JsonIgnore` on the fields which you do not want to be serialized.

```
 public class myDto {

     @Id
     @JsonIgnore
     private String id;
```

More info on the annotation [@JsonIgnore](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html).

Comment: That would work for ID. Apart from ID I also get other two fields as well 
 ["meta":null,"links":null] which are not part of DTO.

Comment: It is not clear to me where the `meta` and `links` is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ObjectMapper to not include fields that return a null value in the JSON.

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)
```